# error decoding array that was returned in json - swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, decoding

when trying to decode the return of the array of objects "arquivo", always nil

```
import UIKit

struct pessoa: Codable {
    let idPessoa: Int
    let nome: String
    let cpf: String
    let email: String
    let dtaNascimento: String
    let dtaCadastro: String
    let telefone: String
    let status: Int

}
struct arquivo: Codable {
    let idArquivo: Int
    let caminho: String
    let nome: String
    let descricao: String
    let tamanho: Double
    let idPessoa: Int
    let idOcorrencia: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case idArquivo
        case caminho
        case nome
        case descricao
        case tamanho
        case idPessoa
        case idOcorrencia
    }
}
struct PessoaDTO: Codable {
    let pessoa: pessoa!
    let arquivo: Array<arquivo>!

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case pessoa = "pessoa"
        case arquivo = "arquivo"
    }
}

var json = """
{
"pessoa":
{
"idPessoa": 89,
"nome": "Arnaldo",
"cpf": "816.404.648-44",
"email": "testeocorrenciabus@google.com",
"dtaNascimento": "1969-01-01T03:00:00.000+0000",
"dtaCadastro": "2019-10-30T18:53:19.000+0000",
"telefone": "(54)58648-4464",
"status": 1,
"arquivo": [
{ "idArquivo": 91,
"caminho": "/images/u/1572461505454.jpg",
"nome": "1572461505454.jpg",
"descricao": "",
"tamanho": 31765,
"idPessoa": 89,
"idOcorrencia": 1
}
]
}
}
"""
do {
    let decodedBeerObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(PessoaDTO.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
    print(decodedBeerObject.pessoa)
    print(decodedBeerObject.arquivo)

} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Result:

> Optional(__lldb_expr_51.pessoa(idPessoa: 89, nome: "Arnaldo", cpf:
>   "816.404.648-44", email: "testeocorrenciabus@google.com",
>   dtaNascimento: "1969-01-01T03:00:00.000+0000", dtaCadastro:
>   "2019-10-30T18:53:19.000+0000", telefone: "(54)58648-4464", status:
>   1)) nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Model is incorrect

`arquivo` is exist inside the `pessoa` not in a same level.

Correct parsing code is :

```
struct Pessoa: Codable {
    let idPessoa: Int
    let nome: String
    let cpf: String
    let email: String
    let dtaNascimento: String
    let dtaCadastro: String
    let telefone: String
    let status: Int
    let arquivo: Array<Arquivo>!

}
struct Arquivo: Codable {
    let idArquivo: Int
    let caminho: String
    let nome: String
    let descricao: String
    let tamanho: Double
    let idPessoa: Int
    let idOcorrencia: Int
}
struct PessoaDTO: Codable {
    let pessoa: Pessoa!  

}

var json123 = """
{
"pessoa":
{
"idPessoa": 89,
"nome": "Arnaldo",
"cpf": "816.404.648-44",
"email": "testeocorrenciabus@google.com",
"dtaNascimento": "1969-01-01T03:00:00.000+0000",
"dtaCadastro": "2019-10-30T18:53:19.000+0000",
"telefone": "(54)58648-4464",
"status": 1,
"arquivo": [
{ "idArquivo": 91,
"caminho": "/images/u/1572461505454.jpg",
"nome": "1572461505454.jpg",
"descricao": "",
"tamanho": 31765,
"idPessoa": 89,
"idOcorrencia": 1
}
]
}
}
"""
do {
    let decodedBeerObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(PessoaDTO.self, from: json123.data(using: .utf8)!)
    print(decodedBeerObject.pessoa)
    print(decodedBeerObject.pessoa.arquivo)

} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: let arquivo: [arquivo]

Answer (score 0):

Your structs are slightly wrong, the key `arquivo` is a part of `Pessoa`

```
struct Pessoa: Codable {
    let idPessoa: Int
    let nome: String
    let cpf: String
    let email: String
    let arquivo: [Arquivo]
    let dtaNascimento: String
    let dtaCadastro: String
    let telefone: String
    let status: Int

}
struct Arquivo: Codable {
    let idArquivo: Int
    let caminho: String
    let nome: String
    let descricao: String
    let tamanho: Double
    let idPessoa: Int
    let idOcorrencia: Int
}

struct PessoaDTO: Codable {
    let pessoa: Pessoa
}
```

Codingkeys are not needed if the name of the key and the struct member matches

To get the **real** error print always only the `error` instance

```
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

And please name structs with starting capital letter.

And **never declare struct members in a `Codable` context as implicit unwrapped optional**.

Comment: yes, I used the first capital letter. This one is only on the playground and i forgot to put it. Thanks!